# Convert date to to_timestamp OracleDB

Tags: java, database, oracle, timestamp

I'm using oracleDB to query for results in a time range. My date objects have a toString: Thu May 01 00:00:00 PDT 2013

How would I convert this date to to_timestamp?

I can do to_timestamp('dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') but then I have to put the date into a string and then parse that string into another string then pass it into the query

Comment: you want `01-00-2013 00:00:00`?

Comment: yes. I can use the calendar and do setTime(dateObject) but it has milliseconds on it

Answer (score 0):

I did n't know exactly it will works or not see

```
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'PDT' yyyy");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(outputFormat1.parse("Thu May 01 00:00:00 PDT 2013")));//01-05-2013 00:00:00
```